# wp-admin won't "remember me" in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: wp-admin, cookies

When I login to wp-admin, I tick the box to "remember me", so I don't have to login again next time.

However, if I close the wp-admin tab, and reopen wp-admin in a new tab, I have to login again.

Alternatively, if I browse to another website, and then return to wp-admin, I have to login again.

This happens in Chrome and Firefox.

It doesn't happen in IE9 - in IE9 I am remembered.

In wp-config.php, 'WP_HOME' & 'WP_SITEURL' are set to the same value.

Any

Comment: Does this happens with other sites "Remember me" feature?

Comment: @brasofilo: no, this only happens with my WP admin.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like some configuration in your browser that keeps cookies only for a session specifically for you site. To make sure the problem is not on Wordress side, deactivate all your plugins and try again.